# Shortcut to create properties in Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When using Android Studio with java, when I hit option/enter on a new variable and I select "create as field", it placed the declaration at the top of the class with the other field variables.

In Kotlin, for me it always puts the declaration right above the function that uses it.  I'm still new to Kotlin, is this a common practice?

If not, is there some preference I can change to make properties get inserted at the top of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current behavior is a shortcoming of the Kotlin plugin. Placement of members created with "Create from usage" will be improved in future updates of the plugin. There is no preference to control the behavior.